# how to convert date into month number?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatetime

I have a column **Month** in my table. The month name and date are stored in this month column like

```
Month    
01-JAN-12 
02-FEB-12
```

and so on.

How do I **convert** the **DATE** into month number such as

```
Month
1 
2
```

etc.

Comment: what is datatype of column `month`?

Comment: go for `datepart(month,getdate())`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select 
to_char(to_date('01-JAN-12','dd-mon-yy'),'mm') from dual;
```

Comment: Keep in mind: `TO_CHAR()` returns a string, not a number. A key consideration because '01' != '1'

Answer (score 15):

[Extract](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) works perfectly for this

> EXTRACT extracts and returns the value of a specified datetime field

```
with fullYear as(
  select (to_date('01-jan-12') + 29*level) dte
    from dual
  connect by level <= 12
  )

select extract(month from dte) month, dte from fullYear ;
```

gives you

```
MONTH       DTE
1           January, 30 2012 00:00:00+0000
2           February, 28 2012 00:00:00+0000
3           March, 28 2012 00:00:00+0000
4           April, 26 2012 00:00:00+0000
5           May, 25 2012 00:00:00+0000
6           June, 23 2012 00:00:00+0000
7           July, 22 2012 00:00:00+0000
8           August, 20 2012 00:00:00+0000
9           September, 18 2012 00:00:00+0000
10          October, 17 2012 00:00:00+0000
11          November, 15 2012 00:00:00+0000
12          December, 14 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

Comment: Doesn't actually address the OP's problem, which is to get the month as a *number* rather than a name.

Comment: @APC: huh? Extract(month from dte) returns the ##, the "Dte" column shown above is just the date returned from the with clause. I added spaces to help that be more apparent, but extract returns a number...

Answer (score 2):

Use  `TO_CHAR` function as in `TO_CHAR(my_column, 'MM')`.

For your specific format you would need the format converter `TO_CHAR(month, 'FmMM')` (thanks to Nicholas Krasnov for this trick).

If your `month` column is not already of a date type you will first need to convert it to a date: `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(month, 'DD-Mon-IY'), 'FmMM')`.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Thank you: I did not know this format trick.

Answer (score 1):

datepart function do this easily

```
SELECT DATEPART(m, getdate())
```

Comment: The post is clearly tagged ORACLE. This solution is not ORACLE.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree regarding writing a case when Oracle offers built-in functionality:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '2012-03-15') FROM DUAL;

SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('01-JAN-12', 'DD-MON-RR')) month_to_number FROM DUAL;

select to_number(to_char(to_date('01-JAN-12','dd-mon-yy'),'mm')) month_to_number from     dual;

select to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'mm')) month_to_number from dual;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "DatePart" function too :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10530_01/doc/epm.931/html_esb_techref/maxl/dml/funcs/datepart.htm

Comment: That's a link to the Hyperion documentation, which doesn't apply to the regular Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score -7):

```
        SELECT  ( CASE yourDate
        WHEN 'Jan' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Feb' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Mar' THEN 3
        WHEN 'Apr' THEN 4
        WHEN 'May' THEN 5
        WHEN 'Jun' THEN 6
        WHEN 'Jul' THEN 7
        WHEN 'Aug' THEN 8
        WHEN 'Sep' THEN 9
        WHEN 'Oct' THEN 10
        WHEN 'Nov' THEN 11
        WHEN 'Dec' THEN 12
       END )
```

Comment: Why write a horrible CASE statement when Oracle's built-in functionality can do this?