# How to get Month Number from field like Jan-19 in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and have a field where dates are stored like JAN-19, FEB-19, etc.. The number is the year. I need to get the Month Number for this field. So, the month number for JAN-19 would be 1, FEB-19 would be 2, etc..

How can I do this?

Comment: So you dates are not stored using a DATE datatype but as strings???

Comment: Yes, they are stored as strings.

Comment: Try reading this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041200/how-to-convert-date-into-month-number. Oracle SQL has a lot of really useful date functions and there are many different ways you could tackle this. The documentation is very helpful.

Comment: See the [Oracle Datetime Format Model documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " they are stored as strings"

Convert the strings to dates, then cast back to strings get the month number.

```
Select col_whatever -- the target column
        ,  to_char(to_date(col_whatever, 'MON-YY'), 'MM') as month_no
from your_table
/
```

Comment: I'd rebuild your table, or create a new one and store the DATES as DATE